# eXcel formula for all column value in one cell separating by ","

Tags: excel

Look at the column A contain value like the below image . I want a formula to do that .
I don't want to solution like

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,",",A2,",",A3,",",A4,",",A5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2016 has a new function called TextJoin() with the syntax

=TextJoin(delimiter, ignore empty cells, range)

With this, you can use the formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A5)
```

[image]

Edit after comment: It's a new formula in Excel 2016. It does not exist in 2010.

But there are many User Defined Functions (UDF) macros that do a better job than Concatenate, and that can be used in Excel 2010. For example [in this post by Jon Acampora](https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/concatenate-range-of-cells/). You will need to use the VBA code in each of the spreadsheets where you want to use that special function, though, and all these spreadsheets need to be macro-enabled sheets for these special functions to work.

Comment: What will be the result for Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 =A1&","&A2&","&A3&","&A4
```

OR create custom VBA function

```
Public Function Join(rng As Range, delimiter As String) As String
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    Join = Join & cell.Text & delimiter
Next cell
' remove the last delimiter
Join = Left(Join, Len(Join) - Len(delimiter))
End Function
```

Comment: I want a dynamic column freezing formula.

Comment: @SurajKhanra What do you mean with `dynamic column freezing formula`? Edit your question and explain your requirements in your question.

Comment: answer will be like @teylyn's answer but I want a formula for Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

For a long list a more complex formula but one that 'auto adjusts' on copy down might suit:

```
=IF(A2="",LEFT(B1&A2&",",LEN(B1&A2&",")-2),B1&A2&",")
```

Assumes a row is inserted at the top with B1 blank. The output would be in ColumnB of the row with the first blank cell in ColumnA after Row1.